# What is $x$ in the Time-Independent Schrödinger Equation?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, notation

I couldn't find this answered anywhere, even though it's absolutely central. What does the value $x$ stand for in the time-independent Schrödinger equation? It's the thing we solve for, but it doesn't say anywhere what it is.

$\Psi (x)$

Comment: It's definitely not true that "$x$ is the thing we solve for". The time independent Schrodinger equation is a(n ordinary) differential equation for a function $\psi(x)$. Have you met differential equations before? If not, I suggest you read up on some simpler ones first.

Comment: Has there been an instance in your studies where the function argument $x$ is *not* position?

Comment: @JohnBig in the simplest variant of Schr. Eq., $x$ is a Cartesian coordinate of a single particle in the chosen frame of reference (usually, so-called lab frame).

Answer (score 1):

$\Psi$ is the wavefunction, which has a value at every position $x$ (1D space, the simplest case).

Answer (score 0):

The Schrödinger equation allows you to find the Wavefunction $\Psi (x)$ that describes the particle (or system) of interest. Solving the equation allows you to obtain all the information that you wish to know about the system (Within the quantum-mechanical boundaries, of course).

The x is simply your variable here. For example, if you have a single particle in a one dimensional box of length L, your x value will be constrained to lie between 0 and L. Thus, your Schrödinger equation will only have a solution (other than 0) between $x=0$ and $x=L$.
If you evaluate your equation at any x, you can find the value of interest (usually expectation values) at said point.

If you are fairly new to QM, I strongly recommend the Griffiths Quantum Mechanics and Zetilli's Quantum Mechanics, both helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ψ is actually a wavefunction, whose value is defined for every position *x*. For systems in time-independent potentials, the wave function can always be written as a function of the degrees of freedom multiplied by a time-dependent phase factor, the form of which is given by the Schrödinger equation. So, you are basically solving for the wavefunction at a particular position "*x*".